# Chrome doesnt show large sized canvas

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-canvas

I have an application that draws over 260 plots on a canvas. The decision to put them on a single canvas was dictated by speed considerations - its much faster that way for various tasks (such as zooming and panning). I.e., splitting to 260 canvases is not an option in this case.

Everything works perfectly fine on Opera, Firefox and IE. Chrome, however, stops displaying the canvas when the height becomes larger than ~8130 pixels (the width is constant - 834 px).

I.e. I have the ability to add/remove charts on fly (they are stacked one upon another), and once the height exceeds 8130 px Chrome simply "hides" the canvas. It remains responsive and no error is thrown - what could be the reason?

Comment: A bug, maybe? Can you reproduce it in a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Appears so, thought may be there are some options in Chrome I'm not aware of? Added a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Y79s3/4/ if you change the height from 8130 to 9130 the canvas is getting "hidden" in Chrome.

Comment: I still display the canvas, but I'm using Chrome 29 dev and it could be a more advanced version than yours. It may also depend on the settings of your video card. I've an AMD HD 6410D integrated in the CPU.

Comment: shows on my Chrome 27 / Mac

Comment: Strange, could be Windows related? I'm using Chrome 28.0.1500.72m / Windows 7

Answer (score 5):

Although the standard specify a unsigned long size for the canvas:

```
interface HTMLCanvasElement : HTMLElement {
           attribute unsigned long width;
           attribute unsigned long height;
```

<sup>*Source: [WhatWG/Canvas element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element)*</sup>

most browsers seem to limit the size to 8192 (Safari apparently to 6826).

In any case (generally speaking) -

If you need a canvas size bigger than that I would say you should definitely re-think the design. Canvas should rarely need to be bigger than what you can actually see on the screen. Consider the canvas as a *view-port* to your data not the holder of it. This is how most operating systems works as well (at low-level) as this has proven to be the best approach over the decades.

Consider the band-width requirements (not completely accurate as this is based on implementation and its optimizations - but for the sake of a pointer to what we're dealing with):

A canvas size of 8192 x 8192 pixels using RGBA buffer consumes 256 MB raw memory (and depending on browser implementation it could be the double).

Update that @ 60Hz and band-width is minimum 15 GB/second. In addition other browser and system content adds to this. If this is used at a typical consumer computer (and not on a developer machine) the theoretical benefit is easily lost.

Yes, you can gain speed by pre-render a large area and move that into view-port by simply blitting the pixels from that to the visible one - up to a certain point and a certain cost (memory being one factor). Some of the speed gain is anyway lost by using JavaScript to move the "blitting source" around compared to more low-level environments where this gain is more significant.

It's in general better to keep your data in a vector format (array/typed array/object) and plot the visual portion of by checking boundaries, ie. what data would be visible in the view-port. You can optimize the data in various ways to access it fast (see for instance [quad-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree)).

Render the vector data is not so costly as one might think (if done "correctly") and the smaller the canvas is the faster it is to clear it and redraw the data.

The main trick however is to blit content that is already on the canvas (same effect as blitting from a huge canvas) and only update the new gaps.

My 2 cents..

Comment: There are cases and there are cases. :-) I wouldnt want to argue about the design itself - several approaches were tried, and under the limitations of JavaScript environment this was found to be the optimal. We're speaking about 120 Mb data on average, that has to be visualized and processed at once. This, without overloading the server and offering a smooth experience on PC. By the way, its strange that only Chrome has this limit, I already convinced myself its a bug? :-)

Comment: The scenario I ran into this limit was where I was storing images from a webcam <video> on the client for replay.  I ran into a canvas # limit first, then tried to tile canvases and then ran into dimension limits.  Its not how canvases are intended to be used, but I haven't found another way to store webcam data.

Comment: @FrankSchwieterman my hope is that the video element or some equivalent will open up to store single frames for video. But as there seem to be problems just agreeing on which formats to use in relation to playback I don't think this will happen anytime soon. Local storage is also an option, such as File API (store cached bundles of images), but there will be a while until this is mature and available enough.